# How to access previous updated_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have model in which I keep track of the field `updated_at`.

Is there a way I can track the previous `updated_at`?

For example

updated_at = A (where A is an actual datetime stamp)

Some work is done then `save` is called

updated_at = B (where B is an actual datetime stamp)

Is there a way I can access the previous `updated_at` i.e. A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) module:

```
object.updated_at           # returns current value
object.updated_at_changed?  # returns true or false if value has changed
object.updated_at_was       # return last value
object.updated_at_change
```

Or

If you wants to track all changed values you can use [Paper Trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) Gem.

Comment: I think these methods only apply to when you change values of an instance object. When you save it those changes are reset. The question asks how to access a previous value after a save has occurred, so I'm not sure this will answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the object available, then you can call:

```
object.previous_changes
```

This would return you a hash as follows showing which attributes have been changed:

```
{"name"=>["foo", "bar"], "updated_at"=>[Tue, 19 Apr 2016 08:19:40 UTC +00:00, Mon, 25 Apr 2016 10:49:47 UTC +00:00]}
```

Refer: 
 [**previous_changes**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes)

Comment: can I do that on the object's attribute?

Comment: You can do it for all the attributes of the object. previous_changes returns all attributes that have changed in the last save/update

Comment: @RPV As `previous_changes`  returns a hash, you can do something like this: `object.previous_changes[:updated_at]` - This would only return the value changed on `updated_at` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

It will be useful if you use [paper trail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail).
It will persist the previous record on disk which may affect your app performance.
Better way to implement an in-memory solution to store the previous records.